# Android L App Drawer

Tags: android, github, android-5.0-lollipop

I am quite new to android development, and have been trying to design an app..
Can anyone tell me, how do I include github projects into my app??

https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer#download

This is the perfect example of what I am trying to do. Can anyone please guide me, by a step by step process, so as to how I can make a fully functional apk from this?

I already have a project, with a working Google Map fragment, on top of that, I am trying to include this type of action bar. 
Can anyone help me?? I am a complete newbie and I would appreciate it very much..
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using Android Studio add this to you build.gradle in the dependencies tag

```
compile 'com.ikimuhendis:ldrawer:0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
```

if your using eclipse down load the the source as a zip and import the library folder form the downloaded file in you current project as a android library.

if can post you code i can help you with it.